# How to do a foreach on a string inside a stdClass inside a array?

Tags: php, foreach

I have this code:

```
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
var_dump($results);
```

I get the following:

```
array(1) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#595 (1) { 
        ["relationto"]=> string(26) "{"0":"3","1":"2","2":"55"}" 
    } 
}
```

But I need a foreach NR after `:`

I asked a similar question before and that question was closed for duplicate ([How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)) I have tried all the suggestions on the page but none work and I think it is because it ain't json. It is saved in the DB as varchar and the vardump says it is a string.

Comment: Telling me how this part is called `"0":"3"` is also very helpful for me to search and make a better title.

Comment: For each number after the `:` I want to do a new search in a db table.

Comment: Try using `print_r( json_decode($results->relationto, true));`.

Comment: @NigelRen I just updated the code and also tried your code this returns: `Notice: Trying to get property 'relationto' of non-object` PS: Thank you for helping

Comment: As you have just changed it - try `print_r( json_decode($results[0]->relationto, true));`

Comment: This is looking good it now gives me a `Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 2 [2] => 55 )` so now I should be able to do a normal foreach right?

Comment: @purple11111 Yes.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you very much for taking the time in helping me it helped a lot.

Comment: @Brewal Thank you for the confirmation. I have made the foreach and it works.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for editing the post and making it a bit better. I am going to make a view changes myself also to make it a better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution came through the comments by Nigel Ren (@nigelren):

```
// Original code
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
var_dump($results);

// Print the results
print_r( json_decode($results[0]->relationto, true));

// Creating the foreach
$datas = json_decode($results[0]->relationto, true);
foreach($datas as $data) {
  echo "<br><br>" . $data . "<br><br>";
}
```